# jquery click within a click causes to much recursion error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As stated in the title I'm having some issues with my JS.

**js:**

```
$("#bg2InsideFb").click(function () {
       $("#fbLink").click();
    });
```

**html:**

```
<div id="bg2InsideFb">
    <p id="fbIcon">
        <img src="@routes.Assets.at("images/mobile/login/fblogin-ico.png")" alt="Facebook"/>
    </p>
    <p class="pl20">
        <a id="fbLink" href="@fb.authenticationUrl"> @Messages("review.form.facebook.login") </a>
    </p>
 </div>
 <p class="floatleft f13">
    @Messages("review.form.facebook.term")
 </p>
```

This results Chrome to crash and Firefox to throw a too much recursion error. What is happening and how do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I did it like this since the propagation solution did not work for me.

```
    $(function () {
        $("#bg2InsideFb, #bg2InsideG").click(function () {
            var tmpLink = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
            window.location.href = tmpLink;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

You are programmatically clicking `#fbLink` which is an element within `#bg2InsideFb`. Event bubbling causes that very same click to effect the later element which then triggers another click. To prevent this, you'll need to hook a listener to the inner element which prevent propagation like this:

```
$('#fbLink').click(function(jqEvt) {
    jqEvt.stopPropagation();
}
```

See the [jQuery API on event.stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

Comment: Hmm I added your code, no error now, but nothing happens. I guess I missed something?

Comment: @jakob I don't even know what it's supposed to do. Since it is a link, I assume new content ought to be loaded. What is your new code?

Comment: Yes you are correct. The new content should be loaded. The code is the same as before I just added the stopPropagation code to js file.

Comment: @jakob There shouldn't be any issue with `stopPropagation`. I'd assume the error to lie somewhere else. Is it an asynchronous request or have you registered more click handlers on anchors?

Comment: Hmm a regular syncronous request to antother page on the same domain If I do $('#fbLink').click(); in chrome console I get back:
[
<a id=​"fbLink" href=​"/​authenticate/​facebook">​ Facebook-konto ​</a>​
] shouldn't click result in clicking on the link and moving to /​authenticate/​facebook

Comment: @jakob It actually should. Try removing both event listeners and see if it works. That would be a place to start... I still doubt it's the `stopPropagation` invokation causing this issue except there is a bug in jQuery. But I doubt that, too...

Comment: Still the same problem... This is very strange!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to trigger #fbLink. In this case you have to use

```
$('#fbLink').click(function(ev) { 
    ev.stopPropagation();  
});
$('#fbLink').triggerHandler('click');``
```

Comment: No, trigger still causes bubbling. I think you meant  .triggerHandler(), but that still doesn't quite answer the OP

Comment: My fault, yes I meant `triggerHandler()`. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for **ev.target** to see if it's the propagation from the inside element.

```
$(document).on('click', '.photoplaceholder', function(e){
    if (!$(e.target).closest('INPUT[type="file"]').length) {
        $(this).find('INPUT[type="file"]').click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling `$("#fbLink").click();` it actually calling its parents also. that's why its causing recursion error. Could you please explain actually what are you want to do?

```
$("#bg2InsideFb").click(function () {
   $("#fbLink").click(function(){
      return false;
   });
});
```

It may works.